# How to send headers and body using Jersey POST request?

Tags: java, rest, post, jersey, content-type

I haven't been able to hit an API successfully. I need to pass three values in the body of the POST request and a header: `"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

I'm getting a 400 status, along with this:
 `Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]`, can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(); 
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(REST_URI).path("dummy/dummy"); // REST_URI is a constant containing the URL

    // Create body content
    String json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("grant_type", "password")
              .add("username", USERNAME) // USERNAME/PASSWORD are constants
              .add("password", PASSWORD)
            .build()
            .toString();


    Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            //.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .post(Entity.entity(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code. You have to use the method .type() where you have to mention content-type.

```
Response response = webTarget.resource(URL)
                             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                             .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                             .post(Entity.entity(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

You can also refer about how to make client from the following link.

https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-restful-client-examples/#post